# Address Book Authentication

Tags: 14.04, gnome, search

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04.1 and run Gnome Shell.

I am consistently getting a pop up window prompting me for my Gmail address book authentication. The window pops up the moment I type something into gnome shell after hitting the super key. I'm assuming that Ubuntu wants to search my address book for people to include in the search.

I have opened up the settings and deleted my account from the online accounts section and rebooted, nothing seems to stop the popup. Where is it getting my email address from? Most importantly, how to I stop this super annoying popup from appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it helps others, I'm posting what worked for me.

It turned out to be evolution, something I had configured a long time ago and had since forgotten about. Careful, this will wipe out your evolution accounts.

```
rm -rfv ~/.config/evolution/sources/*
```

If you don't want to wipe all of your evolution accounts, you have to open each file in `~/.config/evolution/sources/` until your find the right one and delete that one.

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2131506&p=12759547#post12759547)